"object-fit: contain" not working in PrimeNg p-image
CSS "object-fit: contain" does not work in PrimeNg p-image component.
<p-image [src]="image" alt="Image" appendTo="body" height="550vw" width="100%" style="object-fit: contain"></p-image>

Is there anything i missed. Also tried it with a different way with the same result:
[style]="{ objectFit: 'contain' }"


Have you tried imageStyle which is given as an option for styling the actual image in the docs - PrimeNg Image Api Tab.



name
type
default
description




imageClass
string
null
Style class of the image element.


imageStyle
Object
null
Inline style of the image element.


styleClass
string
null
Class of the element.



Snippet:
    <div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-image
        [src]="'https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/galleria/galleria10.jpg'"
        alt="Image"
        appendTo="body"
        height="550vw"
        width="100%"
        [imageStyle]="{objectFit: 'contain'}"
    ></p-image>
    </div>

Stackblitz Demo
